# disable notification for allowing my location using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mutablecapabilities

I am trying to initialize the FirefoxDriver so it can disable the notification of a website for allowing my location. 
    I searched and found this code. But when putting ffprofile on FirefoxDriver() it says cannot resolve constructor.

```
System.setProperty(Utility.MOZILLA_DRIVER, Utility.MOZILLA_PATH);
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Utility class is here:

```
 public class Utility { 
    public static final String MOZILLA_PATH="C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\firefox\\geckodriver.exe"‌​; 
    public static final String MOZILLA_DRIVER="webdriver.gecko.driver"; 
    }
```

The error is like this when running it:

```
Error:(16, 18) java: no suitable constructor found for FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)
constructor org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities)
constructor org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions)
constructor org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
constructor org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService)
```

Comment: Show us what is `Utility.MOZILLA_DRIVER` and `Utility.MOZILLA_PATH`

Comment: public class Utility {

public static final String MOZILLA_PATH="C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\firefox\\geckodriver.exe";
    public static final String MOZILLA_DRIVER="webdriver.gecko.driver";
}

Comment: Update the question with this information _not as_ **comments**

Answer (score 0):

While working with **`Selenium 3.8.1`** you can use the [**FirefoxOptions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) Class  which extends [**`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) to work with [**FirefoxProfile**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) as follows :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class FirefoxProfile_new {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty(Utility.MOZILLA_DRIVER, Utility.MOZILLA_PATH);
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```